# Routing & URL generation issue with optional parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes

I've a small issue with URL generation & routing under ASP.NET MVC 2. My route has optional parameters and the URL is correctly generated if the parameters are specified.

Thus:

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog", "Articles/{tag}/{page}", new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" });
```

with:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(item.Tag, "Index", "Blog", new { tag = item.Tag }, null) %>
```

does correctly generates `~/Articles/item_tag/1`. The link works, my view is rendered.

I have others link like:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("See more articles", "Index", "Blog") %>
```

that generates `~/Blog` instead of `~/Articles`.

If I add a second route like:

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog2", "Articles", new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" });
```

my URL is correctly rendered. I can't understand why I'd need to add this second route as it seems very redundant because the first route has optional segments.

Any help appreciated.

Fabian

EDIT: added routes code.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

// Home
routes.MapRoute("Home", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute("HomeSearch", "Search", new { controller = "Home", action = "Search" });

// Solutions
routes.MapRoute("Solutions", "Solutions", new { controller = "Home", action = "Solutions" });

// Customers
routes.MapRoute("Customers", "Customers", new { controller = "Home", action = "Customers" });

// News
routes.MapRoute("NewsDetails", "News/Details/{id}", new { controller = "News", action = "Details" });
routes.MapRoute("News", "News", new { controller = "News", action = "Index" });

// Articles
routes.MapRoute("BlogDetails", "Articles/Details/{id}", new { controller = "Blog", action = "Details" });
routes.MapRoute("BlogWithTag", "Articles/{tag}/{page}", new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index", tag = "", page = 1 });
routes.MapRoute("Blog", "Articles/{page}", new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index", page = 1 });

// Contact
routes.MapRoute("Contact", "Contact", new { controller = "Contact", action = "Create" });

// Sitemap
routes.MapRoute("Sitemap", "SiteMap", new { controller = "Home", action = "SiteMap" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog", "Articles/{tag}/{page}", new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" });
```

The `{tag}` and `{page}` tokens are not optional. They are hard-coded into the URI and you have no default for them.

Because of the `/` between `{tag}` and `{page}` in your route, this will never generate a URI like `~/Blog`.

Comment: It will if there's another route definition that starts with `"Blog/..."`

Comment: So your suggestion is to keep my "Blog2" route?

Comment: Yes, probably. Hard to be certain without working out a full routing strategy. You should do that, incidentally.

Answer (score 1):

### Non-optional parameters are mandatory

As their name implies, they are **nonoptional**. So if you don't provide `tag` and `page` in your `ActionLink()` call, route won't hit this route definition.

So your example when you call `Html.ActionLink()` and provide `tag` parameter **but not `page`** I guess you must have a different route definition that starts with `Article/...` as well, because your route that you've provided here, is unable to generate your link:

```
/Articles/item_tag/1
```

Route doesn't have any knowledge of parameter types. This means that parameter `page` value was provided by other means either by:

- existing page route data values
- a different route definition

### So what's in it for you?

What's important in your case is that not providing `tag` and `page` parameter values when generating links, your route definition won't get hit and your link will be incorrect.

Why did you actually get `/Blog` link? Simply because you probably still have the default route definition at the end:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

And since you did say that controller is *Blog* and action is *Index* but haven't provided Id, so it will use its default, this will generate your default link URL which is exactly `/blog`. It's quite obvious when you look at it this way isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, I thought that having my controller method with optional parameters would suffice. I've modified my Global.asax.cs file like this:

routes.MapRoute("Blog", "Articles/{tag}/{page}", new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index", tag = "", page = 1 });

But it still doesn't generates the right URL.

Comment: @Fabian Vilers: If you provide your complete route definition from Global.ascx.cs (add it to your question and format it), we will be able to help. **Why?** Simply because it should work with one route that defines defaults for `tag` and `page`. There's no need for second route definition whatsoever if those two parameters have defaults.